# nocache.js not found in Vaadin project

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

"Requested resource [/VAADIN/widgetsets/AppWidgetset/AppWidgetset.nocache.js] not found.." I get this when I'm including new addons, either from a JAR file or through Maven. Sometimes, if I've added the dependency in Maven, adding the JAR file as well to the build path fixes it, sometimes it's the other way around, other times compiling the widgetset and/or theme fixes it, and there are even times when nothing helps. This type of behavior seems to me more random than scientific. 
I would love to know how to properly add dependencies to the project so that I can avoid this problem.

Comment: Please show how you build your project, our magic is currently exthaused, so we don't see what you are doing

Comment: I have created a new Vaadin 8 project in Eclipse using the Vaadin plugin. No customization.  In the POM file I pasted the dependency for FancyLayouts. That's everything.

Answer (score 0):

Select the UI project and goto Properties - Deployment Assembly. Check if you already have widgetset.jar file. If the widgetset.jar is missing then Click on Add -> Maven Project and select widgetset (make sure the jar file naming convention follows backend project like WEB-INF/lib/qqq-widgetset-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and WEB-INF/lib/qqq-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I click Add, this is what I get (screenshot: https://ibb.co/fhh2tp). There is no Maven Project. I looked in each of the available options there,  and there is no widgetset.jar file.

Comment: Are you able to access the widgetset.jar file?